# How to convert the below tuple set into a formatted json using pig?

Tags: json, bash, shell, apache-pig, bigdata

I have the below pig bag with two tuples.

```
{(1,'Kumar','23000','Kandy')}
{(2,'Mahela','34000','Colombo')}
```

How can I convert the above to the following json key value format using pig?

```
{
   1: 'kumar,23000,kandy',
   2: 'mahela',34000,'colombo'
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Please note that I need to store this in a JSON file

After Oliver's answer

```
{"fields":[{"name":"group","type":10,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"test_table_columns_needed","type":120,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":{"fields":[{"name":null,"type":110,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":{"fields":[{"name":"id","type":10,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"name","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"salary","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"destination","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null}],"version":0,"sortKeys":[],"sortKeyOrders":[]}}],"version":0,"sortKeys":[],"sortKeyOrders":[]}}],"version":0,"sortKeys":[],"sortKeyOrders":[]}   {"group":1,"test_table_columns_needed":[{"id":1,"name":"'Kumar'","salary":"'23000'","destination":"'Kandy'"}]}
 {"group":2,"test_table_columns_needed":   [{"id":2,"name":"'Mahela'","salary":"'34000'","destination":"'Colombo'"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple_entry = LOAD 'tuple_array' 
    USING PigStorage() 
    AS ('ref: int, name:chararray, amount:int, surname:chararray');

STORE tuple_entry 
    INTO 'tuple_table.json' 
    USING JsonStorage();
```

Modify the file .pig_schema in order to comply with your tuple inputs.

Comment: JsonStorage stores the json with column names as keys and data as values. But I want the output json to look like the above. Can you please explain how that can be done? Since i'm new to pig not so much familiar with these

Comment: You would simply 'DUMP tuple_entry;'

Comment: Edited the answer with what I get after doing a JsonStorage, it does have column names and meta information :(

Comment: where can I find that file? can you help with an example :( and through the schema I can only specify the data types noh? not the output format

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way as per input data

```
{(1,'Kumar','23000','Kandy')}
{(2,'Mahela','34000','Colombo')}

A = LOAD ' /user/root/test1110_1.txt'  as (t1:(ID:chararray,     Name:chararray,Sal: chararray, Loc:chararray));
B = foreach A GENERATE t1.ID as ID, REPLACE(CONCAT(t1.Name ,',' ,     t1.Sal,',', t1.Loc ), '[\\\'\\(\\)]','') as Val:CHARARRAY ;
STORE B INTO 'tuple_table.json'  USING JsonStorage();

([1#Kumar,23000,Kandy])
([2#Mahela,34000,Colombo])
```